# REINFORCE for VAE Implementation Question

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders, variational-bayes, probabilistic-programming

I want to compute the VAE loss through REINFORCE since my model's decoder is a deterministic program and is non-differentiable. The only REINFORCE implementation for VAE I was able to find used the following code.

```py
# Reconstruction + KL divergence losses summed over all elements and batch
def loss_function(recon_x, x, log_prob, entropy):
    BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(recon_x, x.view(-1, 784), reduce=False).sum(-1)
    # We make the assumption that q(z1,..,zd|x) = q(z1|x)...q(zd|x)
    log_prob = log_prob.sum(-1)
    # The Reinforce loss is just log_prob*loss
    reinforce_loss = torch.sum(log_prob*BCE.detach())
    # If the prior on the latent is uniform then the KL is just the entropy of q(z|x)
    # We add reinforce_loss - reinforce_loss.detach() so we can backpropagate through the encoder with REINFORCE but it doesn't modify the loss.
    loss = BCE.sum() + reinforce_loss - reinforce_loss.detach() + entropy.sum()
    return loss
```

Is the author's implementation correct? First of all, adding and subtracting `reinforce_loss` seems very hacky to me (though perhaps this is correct), and the KL Divergence is simply computed through Entropy(Q) rather than CrossEntropy(Q,P) - Entropy(Q) if P is uniform categorical.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding and subtracting some loss with `.detach()` is a common trick to allow the gradients to go through without changing the value. It's fine.

The cross-entropy of $Q$ with a uniform distribution is constant wrt $Q$, because $H[Q,P] = E_Q[\log P]$. Therefore the term is dropped.